# Bash expansion for numeric character(s)

Tags: bash

Does bash expansion have anything to expand to any numeric character?

For example, so that I can delete all subdirectories whose name start with a number?

Comment: Provide an example of the directory structure and what you are trying to catch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does use path expansion for numeric characters .

`rm path/[0..9]spo`

`echo [0..9]spo`

will result in the removal of any files with the name

`0spo 1spo 2spo 3spo 4spo 5spo 6spo 7spo 8spo 9spo`

that exist .

For more info check out

http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Also related

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option

Comment: Note that this will expand to `0spo 1spo ... 9spo` regardless of which of these actually exist. If you want to expand to only existing ones, use `rm [0-9]spo` instead.

Comment: That's not brace expansion; it's *pathname expansion*.